# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z in OC4J

Tags: java, jpa, oc4j

I made a simple project using among others JPA, but there is a problem using OC4J as a server.

```
[oracle:deploy] Deployment failed for spring.

BUILD FAILED
C:\Resources\springsource\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.oc4j_1.5.206.v20090812\buildfiles\oracle.10.1.3.xml:74: Deploy error: Operation failed with error:
Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z
```

classPath

hibernate3.jar hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar javassist-3.14.0-GA.jar jstl-1.2.jar jstl-impl-1.2.jar jta-1.1.jar log4j-1.2.16.jar ojdbc6.jar org.springframework.asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar org.springframework.context 3.0.5.RELEASE.jar org.springframework.core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar org.springframework.expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar org.springframework.orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar org.springframework.transaction-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar org.springframework.aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar org.springframework.context.support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar org.springframework.instrument-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar org.springframework.test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar

Comment: do you have all required dependencies ? Are you including all jars contained in required folder of Hibernate ?

Comment: yes but the problem is the server

Comment: try remvoing: hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar

Answer (score 1):

Could be the following:

You are having the JPA 1.0 API jar somewhere in your classpath. You need to find and remove the offending jar.

If you are not sure, which JAR. Please post your classpath to your question, so I can take a look.

Comment: i'm using hibernate + spring not ejb

Comment: by adding ejb3-persistence.jar nothing happened

Comment: this make the exception
`<bean id="mySessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"><property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
<property name="packagesToScan">
    <list>
        <value>com.ali.model</value>
    </list>
</property>`